# SAS- Supress Results view on some, but not all, proc print ods outputs

Tags: sas, sas-ods

I want to be able to print all of my reports to external files but only display a select few in the results viewer. In the below example I want reportA and reportB to be displayed AND printed (file.xls) but reportC to be printed to a separate file (file2.csv) and not displayed in the results viewer. Any ideas?

```
ods msoffice2k file="/file/file.xls";
proc print data=reportA;
run;
proc print data=reportB
run;
ods msoffice2k close;
ods csvall file="/file/file2.csv";
proc print data=reportC;
run;
ods csvall close;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a better solution through using the `proc export` feature for suppressing display of the csv output.

```
ods msoffice2k file="/file/file.xls";
proc print data=reportA;
run;
proc print data=reportB
run;
ods msoffice2k close;

proc export data=reportC
outfile="/file/file2.csv"
dbms=dlm
replace;
delimiter=",";
run;
```

Thanks for the help @Reeza I'll keep those settings in mind for future projects.

Comment: Proc Export does work well :) The only thing to keep in mind is how it treats formatted variables and ensure that they're exported in the manner you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `ODS EXCLUDE` and `ODS SELECT` to target specific destinations.

For example,  `ods html select none;` will turn off the HTML destination temporarily, but not actually close it - it just won't get any results for a while.  You can then use `ods html select all;` to turn it back on.

You can also use `ods html exclude all;` to do the same thing and then turn it back on with `ods html exclude none;`.

With either statement, you can also use a `where` statement in the ods select/exclude to filter to only affect one specific part of an output.  See the [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/odsug/65308/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0edvjbwu4y1bun1qgmzbk3s3vix.htm) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Close the list output which is the default. OR the HTML if that is the default results window in your system. Re-open the output after the file is created.

```
ods msoffice2k file="/file/file.xls";
proc print data=reportA;
run;
proc print data=reportB
run;
ods msoffice2k close;
ods listing close;
ods html close;
ods csvall file="/file/file2.csv";
proc print data=reportC;
run;
ods csvall close;
ods listing;
ods html;
```